# Is It Possible to change or unset Class object during include file?

Tags: php, class, object, include

I have 3 files `StartTrack.php`, `AustPost.php` and `print_order.php`.

`StartTrack.php`, `AustPost.php` in this both files i have declared `Class` and it's `object` and in `print_order.php` i am just including both files based on condition.

> For example (In `print_order.php`) :

I got shipping methods **"startrack"** And **"auspost"**.

If i found **startrack**  then  `StartTrack.php` file is include else include `AustPost.php`.

So actually i stuck when there multiple orders i got.

For example :: i have total 3 orders, in loop i got there are 2 orders are `startrack` and 1 is `austpost` so `StartTrack.php` will be included 2 times and 
`AustPost.php` file one time but problem is  `StartTrack.php` is included only once.

Following is my code...

1 ) `print_order.php`

```
foreach($ordersinfo['order'] as $orders){
     $customerDeliveryMethod = $orders['delivery_method']; 
     if($customerDeliveryMethod == 'startrack'){
        include("StarTrack.php");

    }elseif ($customerDeliveryMethod == 'austpost') {
        include("AusPost.php");

    }
}
```

2) `StartTrack.php`

```
class StarTrack 
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        echo "StarTrack File Called";
    }
}


$StarTrack = new StarTrack;
```

3) `AustPost.php`

```
class AusPost 
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        echo "AusPost File Called";
    }
}


$AusPost = new AusPost;
```

I could not show my full code because of it's too large in all files i am just adding necessary parts of code in each files.

So my main instance is to find out file will be included multiple times based on shipping methods value.

**Startrack** have 2 orders to this file will include 2 times not once and **Auspost** file will include only 1 time because it has only one order.

Please help me how could i resolve this, Is there any class object issue or other?

Comment: Do `require_once` instead of `include`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya , yes i have used require_once  also include_once but not work only one time include file.

Comment: I think using __autoload can solve the issue (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.autoload.php)